# Unsure about singleton variable warning and unbound variable error

Tags: prolog

Writing a Prolog recursive rule `count3(L, P, Z, N)` where 
`L` is a list of integers, `P` is the number of positive numbers in `L`, `Z` is the number of zeros in `L`; `N` is the number of negative numbers in `L`.

```
count3(L, P, Z, N) :-
   count3(L, O, O, O, P, Z, N).

count3([], P, Z, N, P, Z, N).
count3( [X|L], A, B, C, P, Z, N) :-
   tick(X,A,B,C,A1,B1,C1), 
   count3(L,A1,B1,C1,P,Z,N).

tick(X, P, Z, N, P1, Z, N) :- % positive
   X > 0,
   P1 is P+1.

tick(Z, P, Z, N, P, Z, N1) :- % negative
   X < 0,
   N1 is N+1.

tick(X, P, Z, N, P, Z1, N) :- % zero is unsigned
   X == 0,
   Z1 is Z+1.
```

Getting a warning: singleton variables [X] for tick/7 and 
fatal error: unbound variabel in arithmetic expression. Any help appreciated.

Comment: yup. don't know how I missed that.  Just fixed. thanks.

Comment: `tick/7` still has a singleton. You are checking `X < 0` in `tick(Z, P, Z, N, P, Z, N1)` which has no other `X`.